# Xcode 6 smaller screen testing on device

Tags: screen, device, xcode6

I am running Xcode 6 when I test my app on my device (not my simulator) it shows the app on a smaller screen , much like the iPhone 4 screen !? , how do I fix that ???

Comment: Also have this problem. This is the same behaviour you'd expect in older Xcode versions when you forgot to add Default@2x... whatever launch image.

Comment: when I upgraded my phone to IOS 8 it got it's normal size , also I noticed that part of the applications that was designed to IOS 7 also run at a smaller screen :D , weird thing by apple

Answer (score 0):

add these three default image:

Default-568h@2x.png (640x1136)
, Default-375w-667h@2x.png (750x1334)
, Default-414w-736h@3x.png (1242x2208) or Default-414w-736h-landscape@3x.png (2208x1242).

to your app root folder